# Tomcat in eclipse generated a war file with .war? extension

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, solr

When i use tomcat plugin in Eclipse to generate war file, it gave me a name as solr.war? instead of solr.war. I dont understand why there is an extra question mark. Maybe i did something wrong? Thanks!

PS: i am using Eclipse Indigo, Tomcat 7, Solr 3.6, so i include all these tags with this question.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the file is named like that (look at it outside eclipse) or is just some Team plugin showing you the file is not added to the repository??

Comment: Albert, I fixed the solr.war? by renaming it to solr.war. And tomcat unpacked it correctly when i restart the tomcat. I dont know what happened to the tomcat plugin within Eclipse. Basically in the project properties (in Eclipse) i choosed Tomcat and then on the "Export to WAR settings", i gave a correct file name and path like "/Users/nan/Solr/solr.war" but generated a file called "solr.war?"...anyway, lucky that the file is usable.